# Show $X_t = X_{t-}$ a.s. for a Levy process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$

Tags: levy-processes

I started reading Sato's book on Lévy processes. On page 6 it says that for $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ Lévy process

$$X_t=X_{t-},$$
for any fixed $t>0$ almost surely. It is mentioned it follows from the fact that almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability. I think it makes no sense. Can someone explain it?

Comment: Almost sure converge always implies convergence in probability: just follows directly from their definitions. What doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and denote by $\Delta X_t := X_t-X_{t-}$ the jump height at time $t$. Then

$$\begin{align} \mathbb{P}(|\Delta X_t|>\varepsilon) &= \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{k \geq j} |X_t-X_{t-1/k}| > \varepsilon \right) \\
&= \mathbb{P} \left( \liminf_{k \to \infty} |X_t-X_{t-1/k}|>\varepsilon \right) \\
&\leq \liminf_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_{1/k}|>\varepsilon) = 0 \end{align}$$

where we used Fatou's Lemma and the fact that $(X_t)_t$ has stationary increments (i.e. $X_t-X_{t-1/k} \sim X_{1/k}$) and is continuous in probability. Consequently,

$$\mathbb{P}(X_t \not= X_{t-}) = \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |\Delta X_t|> \frac{1}{k} \right) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of a Levy process, for $s <t$, $X_t - X_s$ has the same distribution as $X_{t-s}$ and $ \lim_{u \to 0^+} X_u = 0 \ \text{ almost surely.}$
So
$$ X_{t-} = \lim_{s \to t} X_s = \lim_{s \to t} \{ X_t - (X_t - X_s )\} \underset{as}{=} X_t - X_0 = X_t. $$